# Generate words from random string and match with list's string

Tags: python

```
lst = ["cat","baby","dog","giraffe","man"]
string1 = "tbdcgaianm"
output -> cat,man
string2 = "bsaysad"
output -> None
string3 = "aobdcgt"
output -> cat, dog
```

I am fresher and leaning programming, could you help me on above program "Generate words from random string and match with list's strings and print them.

Comment: I guess you need to pick easier exercises if you are learning to code

Comment: The first step is to understand the task as precisely as possible (e.g. do you know why `bsaysad` returns `None`?).  Then break it down into a series of logical steps to arrive at the result - just thinking about the problem, or perhaps writing them down on paper as if they were instructions to explain to someone else how to get the result.  Then you can research how to program each of the steps in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a litte chain of loops ,-)

```
lst = ["cat","baby","dog","giraffe","man"]
def find_string_in_lst(lst, random_string):
    return_msg = []
    for word in lst: # test each word in list
        tmp_random_string = random_string
        contains_word = []
        for char in word: # test each charater
            if char in tmp_random_string:
                tmp_random_string = tmp_random_string.replace(char, '', 1) # 1 -> only replace one (first) occurence
                contains_word.append(True)
            else:
                contains_word.append(False)
        if all(contains_word):
            return_msg.append(word)
    if not return_msg:
        return_msg = None
    return return_msg

for string1 in ["tbdcgaianm","bsaysad","aobdcgt"]:
    print(string1, '->', find_string_in_lst(lst, string1))
```

Output:

```
tbdcgaianm -> ['cat', 'man']
bsaysad -> None
aobdcgt -> ['cat', 'dog']
```